# Is it possible to create a laser beam using sunlight that generates a wavelength of about 500nm?

Tags: energy, photons, laser

Someone  else on this site inquired about how to [create a laser from sun light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251298/create-a-laser-from-sun-light). There were many ideas on this, but they were all based on DIY ideas. I am more specifically looking into creating a laser beam of 500 nm using sunlight since the sun emits most of its energy around that range. How would you capture the light in order to focus it into a beam? I would like to add some clarification based on the answers I am recieving. I am trying to focus sunlight into a laser so I can then aim it at a PPLN crystal. These crystals need a laser in order to be able to work, therefore I must modify sunlight into a beam. It must be in the form of a laser because I cannot amplify the frequency of sunlight until it has the laser-like features making it coherently phase matching. There must be two photons perfectly in phase in order to be paired together to double frequency.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A laser doesn't focus light.

Comment: related: [Is it possible to focus sunlight from space on a tiny spot on Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409495/192918). I mean, through the following process you can achieve:collect on the mirror, focus it on another mirror, obtain parallel light (with some divergence that depends on some angles), filter it and you'll have your sun powered laser.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to buy some photovoltaic panels, and use them to power a green laser pointer that you buy from the store.

Laser light isn’t focused light, or even really monochromatic light (although laser beams are frequently focused, and are generally quite monochromatic). Laser light is *coherent*, which means that the electric and magnetic fields everywhere in the laser beam are oscillating in phase with each other. In general, coherent laser light is produced in some resonant medium which amplifies one wavelength while suppressing others. (“Laser” began as an acronym, for “light *amplification* by stimulated emission of radiation.”)

Compare with sound. Laser light is like a single musical note, with all of the power in a single frequency/wavelength of oscillation.  White light is like crowd noise, or the sound of the surf at a beach. You can’t extract a single note by listening to the beach noise and throwing away most of the frequencies.

Note that you can extract highly monochromatic light from sunlight, by being clever with prisms and diffraction gratings. But monochromatic sunlight is still not coherent. The technical phrase might be that the “coherence length” of a ray of sunlight is always small compared to any interesting experiment.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the spectrum of many lasers is actually comb-like. If the amplifier bandwidth is wider than the distance between two resonator modes, then a laser can perfectly well produce several (sometimes many) equidistant frequencies at the same time. I think we had a question about that the other day where multiple lines were showing up in an FFT spectrum. In musical terms... maybe a laser is like a choir singing the same note... ? :-)

Comment: [A bio-acoustical variable-intensity frequency comb](https://youtu.be/UHTF1-IhuC0). Makes an excellent party trick. Probably beyond the pedagogical level of this answer, but your pedantry is appreciated.

Comment: @FlatterMann Good point. My inexpensive green laser pointer has three modes near 532 nm. They are separated my about 0.1 nm, as revealed by my echelle spectrograph.

Comment: @EdV That's actually pretty good. I would have guessed that the spectrum of those things would be a mess.

Comment: @rob I am speechless.

Comment: @FlatterMann Correct again: it is kind of a mess. The nominal wavelength fluctuates, as nicely demonstrated by Joel Tellinghuisen using a few green laser pointers and an iodine vapor fluorescence cell, etc. Reference: J. Tellinghuisen, Laser-Induced Fluorescence in Gaseous I_2 Excited with a Green Laser Pointer, J. Chem. Ed., 84(2) 2007 336-341.

Comment: @EdV Nice experiment, indeed. It shows why optical isolation between the source and the sample is important. It also means that Coherent is not going out of business because of cheap Chinese laser pointers anytime soon. Damn, one could have made a killing on their stock, too... but now it's down again. Wonder what happened.

Comment: You start out by saying a laser isn't monochromatic, then proceed to describe how it is monochromatic.  (single musical note)

Comment: @Matt Apart from the question of bandwidth (which quantifies “how monochromatic”), another commenter has already pointed out the existence of multi-mode lasers. If you come across a good acoustical analogy for coherence, I’m interested to learn about it.

Answer (score 2):

There have been a variety of solar pumped lasers, including the idea of putting them on satellites. The critical component is often the solar concentrator to excite the gain medium.  The other issue is much of the solar spectrum is wasted, and light not absorbed by the laser rod or gain medium is wasted or creates a heat problem. So from a fundamental point of view, it can be done, but usually the question is why would you want to do it? Other than it kind of interesting and neat to do, since most other ways of pumping lasers are more efficient.

A recent [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42005-020-0326-2) tries to get around having a complicated solar concentration system by having a dye surrounding, an optical fiber that would act as the laser. The light collected from the sun pumps the dye, the dye emits light that more efficiently pumps the optical fiber, and the laser light comes out of the optical fiber.

But if you look around for other solar pumped lasers you will find a variety of approaches, using a variety of solar concentration techniques like fresnel lenses, or parabolic concentrators etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Sun light pumped lasers is that Sun light is very dilute, but several ways to concentrate it in order to achieve the lasing threshold have been proposed. There is a recent proposal based on the antenna complexes of bacterial photosynthetic organisms: ["Bio-inspired natural sunlight-pumped lasers"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ac2852). Such systems absorb dilute sunlight over a hierarchy of energy scales and could efficiently funnel this energy to a low energy lasing state.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).